# Remove whole row from Google Sheet

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gdata, google-sheets-api

How I can remove whole row from GoogleSheet if I know row index?
Also it should be deleted in one batch.

I using `Google.GData.Spreadsheets`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Delete rows or columns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns)

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 4
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: How would I write that in C#?

Comment: @AmirNo-Family https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Thanks mate for the link. I just don't know to translate JSON requests to C# using the nuget packages.